# Is it possible to prevent an entire XCode rebuild upon 'flutter run'?

Tags: xcode, flutter

building and running my Flutter app using `flutter run` takes a while (~200 seconds). While the hot reload and restart are useful features, certain exceptions can crash the app when running native code (I need them for voice recognition). This forces me to run the entire build again.

An alternative is to run the app from within Xcode. This prevents me from using the hot reload and restart but when the app is already built, it restarts in 20-30 seconds, since I assume it is not rebuilding my Pods from scratch every time.

My question is if it is possible to pass `flutter run` some arguments in order to mimic the Xcode build behavior: To not rebuild everything from scratch every time, but also allow hot reload and restart.

Please let me know if I should provide more information to my project/system.

Comment: I have the same problem. It would be great if someone knew the answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command line option worked for me for recent Flutter stable version:

```
--use-application-binary=./build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/YourApp.app
```